# Number of sockets opened increased while profiling

Tags: sockets, jdbc, neo4j, profiling, tomcat8

I am currently profiling a Tomcat 8.5 application which uses DBCP as standard pool for Neo4j JDBC Driver connections.

What I do not understand is why the number of sockets opened (and not closed) is so high when I start profiling the application (with Yourkit or JProfiler) and this number is low and stable without profiling. Same behavior confirmed with `lsof` and `ls /proc/my_tomcat_pid/fd | wc -l` commands.

So I am wondering if my application is really not releasing Neo4j JDBC connections as it should, or if it is overhead introduced by the profiler.

Any clue ?

Comment: A connection pool keeps connections in its pool, those use sockets... And a lot of connection pools pre-populate the pool on startup (not sure if DBCP specifically does that)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it was a Yourkit bug linked with Neo4j JDBC driver and Databases probe, which was quickly fixed by Yourkit team. The fix is available in Build 75 : https://www.yourkit.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=39801

Answer (score 0):

If you are using YourKit profile you can run dedicated "Not closed socket connections" inspection https://www.yourkit.com/docs/java/help/event_inspections.jsp Profiler will show you where not-closed sockets were created and opened.